# Chunked transfer encoding - Page is not displayed properly

Tags: c, http, server, chunked-encoding, http-chunked

My task is to implement simple HTTP server. I should support chunked transfer encoding when I send response. Here is my function that send response to client.

```
static int serve_request(int sock, struct conf_arg *arg, char version[])
{
    FILE *html = NULL;
    char buf[MAX_MSG];

    strcat(arg->root, arg->defdoc);
    html = fopen(arg->root, "r");
    if (!html) {
        not_found(sock, version);
        return 0;
    }
    good_responce(sock, version);
    do {
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), html);
        const unsigned chunk = CHUNK_SIZE;
        char *pbuf = buf;
        char tempbuf[chunk + 10];

        while (strlen(pbuf) >= chunk) {
            sprintf(tempbuf, "%x\r\n", chunk);
            write(sock, tempbuf, strlen(tempbuf));
            write(sock, pbuf, chunk);
            pbuf += chunk;
            strcpy(tempbuf, "\r\n");
            write(sock, tempbuf, strlen(tempbuf));
        }
        if (strlen(pbuf) == 0) {
            sprintf(tempbuf, "%x\r\n", 0);
            write(sock, tempbuf, strlen(tempbuf));
        }
        if (strlen(pbuf) > 0) {
            sprintf(tempbuf, "%x\r\n", (unsigned)strlen(pbuf));
            write(sock, tempbuf, strlen(tempbuf));
            write(sock, pbuf, strlen(pbuf));
            sprintf(tempbuf, "%x\r\n", 0);
            write(sock, tempbuf, strlen(tempbuf));
        }
        strcpy(tempbuf, "\r\n");
        write(sock, tempbuf, strlen(tempbuf));
    } while (!feof(html));
    fclose(html);
    return 0;
}
```

`CHUNK_SIZE` is defined as 1024 because I want to sent chunks with 1KB size. The problem occurs when I open page [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f6aM.png)
The page is not displayed properly.
Also I set Transfer-Encoding: chunked

```
strcpy(buf, ENCODING);
send(sock, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
```

ENCODING is defined as "Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n"

Comment: Have you set response header to indicate your response is chunked eg Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Comment: I edit question and add code where I set response header.

Comment: `strcpy()` is superfluous there, you should send the `ENCODING` directly, and then `send(sock, "\r\n", 2, 0)`.

Comment: I change code as you say, but in this case I got error ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know where the problem is, but am not entirely sure.

In your `do` loop, you get a `buf` full of data and you send that. Then you get another buffer full of data and send that. But after having sent each buffer of data, you *terminate* the transfer by sending a `0\r\n`. For example:

```
1024    // send first chunk
1024    // send second chunk
256     // last part of first bufer
0       // terminate transfer
1024    // send first chunk of second buffer
1024    //...
256
0
```

Although it may be better to fill your buffer again before sending the last chunk (use `memmove` to move the last part down, then call `fgets` to fill the remainder), you may be "saved" by sending the `0\r\n` only after the `do ... while` loop, e.g.:

```
        if (strlen(pbuf) > 0) {
            sprintf(tempbuf, "%x\r\n", (unsigned)strlen(pbuf));
            write(sock, tempbuf, strlen(tempbuf));
            write(sock, pbuf, strlen(pbuf));
            //sprintf(tempbuf, "%x\r\n", 0);
            //write(sock, tempbuf, strlen(tempbuf));
        }
        //strcpy(tempbuf, "\r\n");
        //write(sock, tempbuf, strlen(tempbuf));
    } while (!feof(html));
    sprintf(tempbuf, "%x\r\n", 0);
    write(sock, tempbuf, strlen(tempbuf));
    strcpy(tempbuf, "\r\n");
    write(sock, tempbuf, strlen(tempbuf));
```

Note also that you *must* check the result of `fgets` as it can return zero upon eof; the buffer will not have been refreshed and you will send the last part again:

```
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), html)==NULL) break;
```

See also the comments about your unnecessary use of `tempbuf`.

Comment: But when you check return value of fgets() you should compare it to NULL.